# How to navigating through JSON node structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension, which call a webservice that send me a SOAP XML message. When i received this message, i have to navigate on it to parse it but i'm having some problem with it.

The structure of the xml is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<env:Envelope     xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     
            xmlns:ns1="/service.php?service=components" 

            xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 

            xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 

            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 

            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<env:Body xmlns:rpc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc">

<ns1:getComponentsResponse env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<rpc:result>return</rpc:result>

<return enc:itemType="enc:Struct" enc:arraySize="7" xsi:type="enc:Array">

<item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
        <m_type xsi:type="xsd:string">image</m_type>
        <m_params enc:itemType="enc:Struct" enc:arraySize="4" xsi:type="enc:Array">
            <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
                <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">image</m_name>
                <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">9f00de47f9f07ec0c7389875e4739c2b.png</m_value>
                <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">3</m_numType>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
                <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">weblink</m_name>
                <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.xxx.com</m_value>
                <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</m_numType>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
                <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">redirect-type</m_name>
                <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</m_value>
                <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_numType>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
                <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">is-logo</m_name>
                <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</m_value>
                <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_numType>
            </item>
        </m_params>
        <m_order xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_order>
        <m_childs enc:itemType="xsd:anyType" enc:arraySize="0" xsi:type="enc:Array"/>
        <m_id xsi:type="xsd:int">119</m_id>
        <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">image_4d624ce18aeb3</m_name>
    </item>
```

The code is like this :

```
var json = $.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);
alert(json.item[0].length);
```

So basicelly i need to navigate throught the "item", but it didn't works and i don't understand for which reason...

Answer (score 0):

Since XML has only one root tag, when the xmlToJSON plug-in does the parsing, it seems it is not treating the top-level `<item/>` as a child, but rather as the root of the object itself as well.

I'd try:

```
alert(json.m_name);
```

...or whatever child element you were interested in.

If this implementation is the one at http://www.terracoder.com/index.php/xml-objectifier/xml-objectifier-examples , you can do:

```
alert(root._children.length);
```

I'd use a utility like http://phpjs.org/functions/var_export:578 (or do it yourself by using for...in) to reflect on objects such as these, so you can see for yourself what its components are.

**UPDATE**

I don't know anything about using jQuery with Chrome extensions, so my tests were with the stand-alone version. You might try verifying your XML works with that first, and go from there. E.g., this works if you include the XMLObjectifier from http://www.terracoder.com/scripts/saXMLUtils.js first:

```
// XML truncated to be well-formed
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
    <item     xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"\
        xmlns:ns1="/service.php?service=components" \
        xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" \
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" \
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\
        xmlns:rpc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc"\
        xsi:type="enc:Struct">\
    <m_type xsi:type="xsd:string">image</m_type>\
    <m_params enc:itemType="enc:Struct" enc:arraySize="4" xsi:type="enc:Array">\
        <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">\
            <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">image</m_name>\
            <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">9f00de47f9f07ec0c7389875e4739c2b.png</m_value>\
            <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">3</m_numType>\
        </item>\
        <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">\
            <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">weblink</m_name>\
            <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.xxx.com</m_value>\
            <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</m_numType>\
        </item>\
        <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">\
            <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">redirect-type</m_name>\
            <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</m_value>\
            <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_numType>\
        </item>\
        <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">\
            <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">is-logo</m_name>\
            <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</m_value>\
            <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_numType>\
        </item>\
    </m_params>\
    <m_order xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_order>\
    <m_childs enc:itemType="xsd:anyType" enc:arraySize="0" xsi:type="enc:Array"/>\
    <m_id xsi:type="xsd:int">119</m_id>\
    <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">image_4d624ce18aeb3</m_name>\
</item>';

    // DOMParser is only Firefox/Safari/Chrome/IE9+ but convenient for debugging:
xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xml);
var str = '';
for (var i in json) {
    str += i + '::' + json[i] + '\n';
}
alert(str);
```

You might also try this on your XML:

```
var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlhttp.responseXML);
alert(xmlString);
```

Comment: Nop it didn't work... All the time says "undifined"

The link from terracoder, is the one i come from ;)

Comment: Are you sure the XML is well-formed. It works for me with the stand-alone version when the XML is well-formed (your XML above is not well-formed).

Comment: If you paste in your complete XML, we can take a look at what might be going on. Did you confirm the responseXML is even XML? It may be === null if there is a problem with the XML.

Comment: As i tell you it's just a part of my xml. I've juste test : if(json == null) and it don't enter on it. So my Xml seems to be well formed.

The main problem is that i don't know how i can navigate...

Comment: I really appreciate your help dude.

I've test your code, the first one give me back this : http://img715.imageshack.us/i/unledjls.png/

And the second one give me back all my XML File.

Comment: It looks like you have received an HTML document from your server and no an XML file. My guess is that you are getting an error message instead of your intended XML, and that's why you are getting a response. Did you try this code on your responseXML?:  `alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlhttp.responseXML));`

Comment: (The check I just mentioned will not work in IE prior to IE9 though it will work in Firefox, Chrome, etc.